# how to pass multiple rows from an excel sheet as array parameter to Mongodb aggregate and update function?

Tags: arrays, node.js, excel, mongodb, aggregation-framework

We are reading data from Excel Sheet. Each row is combined into one array.

```
Consider these are the two sample data rows from an excel sheet

1st row : A| B|C|D|E|F|G|H
2nd row: I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P
Each Alphabet indicates columns.
```

what we tried is :

```
   for(e in bulkData) // bulkdata is the data from excel sheet
    {
         Coaslsubs = bulkData[e].sub1 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub2 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub3 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub4 + "|"+bulkData[e].sub5 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub6 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub7 + "|"+bulkData[e].sub8;
        Coaslsubs = Coaslsubs.replace('undefined', '');
        Coaslsubs = Coaslsubs.replace('||', '');
        Coaslsubs=","+Coaslsubs;
       console.log(Coaslsubs);  // All row data gets displayed here

         Coaslsubsnew = bulkData[e].sub1 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub2 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub3 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub4 + "|"+bulkData[e].sub5 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub6 +"|"+ bulkData[e].sub7 + "|"+bulkData[e].sub8;
        Coaslsubsnew=Coaslsubsnew.replace('undefined','');

  COASL.aggregate(
          [
              { $match: {"items":"Products"} },
              { $project: { sl: { $concat: [ "$sl", Coaslsubs] } } }
          ],function(err, added) {
            console.log(added);
            if( err || !added ) {
              console.log("Row not added.");

            }
            else {
                      // some code
                  }}
```

when array "Coaslsubs" is passed, it updates only one row in the document in MongoDB.we also tried For loop but nothing worked. In the console, all the row data gets displayed but when passed to an aggregate function only one row gets updated. 
How to pass all the row data from an excel sheet?
Any help is greatly appreciated. THANKS in advance.